# How to efficiently retrieve data from DB to populate selectonemenu

Tags: java, jsf-2, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1, jsf-2.2

Let's say I have this entity called `Customer`. `Customer` objects can be created, deleted or edited in the application.

I create a composite component reprensenting a list of `Customer`, so that I can reuse it in several places in my application.

```
<!-- INTERFACE -->
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="val" required="true"/>
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>
    <p:selectOneMenu value="val">
        <f:selectItems value="#{appManager.customers}"
                       var="cust"
                       itemLabel="#{cust.name}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</cc:implementation>
```

This component is bound to an `@ApplicationScope` managed bean using an EJB.

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppManager {
    @EJB
    private CustomerFacade customerFacade;

    public AppManager() {
    }

    public List<Customer> customers(){
        return customerFacade.findAll();
    }
}
```

But each time this component will be used, the `Customer` table will be fetched, am I right? How can I retrive this `Customer` collection more efficiently? I thought of using lazy-loading of a collection:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppManager {

    @EJB
    private CustomerFacade customerFacade;
    private List<Customer> customers;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of AppManager
     */
    public AppManager() {
    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        if(customers == null){
            customers = customerFacade.findAll();
        }
        return customers;
    }
}
```

But then the changes applied to the DB wouldn't be reflected on the collection.

I would greatly appreciate some advice on the common techniques or best practices in this situation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The usage depends on the situation.

In case data is changed infrequently the way you did it (apart from the fact that it'd be wise to initialize in `@PostConstruct` method) seems quite fine. Think of it as initializing application-wise defaults, like a list of *countries*. You can of course do some checks to see whether the constants have changed automatically/manually to update the contents.

In case the data is subject to constant changes/updates your way of fetching data is very inefficient, as you shouldn't be caching data application-wide. The most efficient way I can think of is to bind that data to a `@ViewScoped` bean instance and [implement pagination of data](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying) in case there is much to be (pre)loaded, or do it via query parameters, as in your case of *customers*. Of course, you can fetch all data in case there are few items to be loaded, like a list of *items in a particular order*.

All in all, I'd implement your solution in the following manner:

1. Create a view scoped bean holding the current page data (a subset of custoimers, say 20), and current paging status (current page, next/previous/total pages, etc.);
2. Provide for the ability to switch to another subset of data in your view and update the bean data accordingly;
3. Introduce a new method in your EJB, next to `findAll`, like e.g. `public List<Customer> find(int from, int to)`.

You can alternatively comunicate via `<f:param>`/`<f:viewParam>` as well, to keep the URLs bookmarkable.

Comment: I picked a wrong example with `Customer`, my data set _may_ change but _won't_ change that much and won't be very large so pagination wouldn't be useful. _You can of course do some checks to see whether the constants have changed automatically/manually to update the contents_: Could you be more specific or give an example?

Answer (score 0):

skuntsel has some very good points, so I am only going to suggest alternatives.

I would move the customer caching in `customerFacade`. Then I would:

1. Make sure the List is a volatile readonly list or a `copyonwritearraylist` (provided that it is not changed very frequently
2. Add hook methods to your EJB that update the list when a value is added/removed/edited
3. Make sure that list data are read-only as they will be shared across threads.

Don't forget that most JPA implementations cache entities as well (and you can also set them up with 3rd party caches), so operations might be faster than you expect.

If data are very small, I would go for skuntsel suggestion and use a `@ViewScoped` bean. It is much easier, less complexity, cleaner and assuming you use Ajax the hit will only be  suffered once.

Comment: I think I will indeed go with `@ViewScoped` like @skuntsel suggested and trust the container to cache the entities.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question:

> But each time this component will be used, the Customer table will be fetched, am I right?

Is: **depends**. Assuming that you are using container managed persistence context, it might be yes or no depending on the configuration of your persistence provider defined in your persistence.xml file (or the defauls of your provider). If you use EclipseLink, object cache (related to objects IDs) is enabled by default, and the query cache might de activated adding this property to the persistence-unit section of your persistence.xml:

```
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

It's easy to check if it is working on the cache or not. Deploy your application and make a query findAll(). After this, insert a new customer directly in DB and  reload all the customers using the findAll() query. I'm pretty sure that the new customer won't be loaded, indicating the persistence manager used it's cache to return the result.

IMHO the best approach is to let the container manage the persistence context. So, in your case, leave your front end code the way it is and just  add a service in your CustomerFacade to insert (CRUD) customers in your DB, this way, the new customers will be reflected in the cache automatically (this is the magic of container managed persistence unit!).

Comment: I was pretty sure the container would cache my entities, but I didn't know about `eclipselink.query-results-cache`, thanks

Comment: Sometimes you really need to bypass the cache. In this case you can force the query to do not check cache using (If you use the EclipseLink provider): query.setHint("eclipselink.cache-usage", "DoNotCheckCache"); You use this code before executing the query. This way you force this specific run of the query to fetch data directly from DB (it works for both named and native queries).